# php not remembering variable when I use jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I have an issue with php not remembering variable when I use jQuery ajax.
Could you help me how I can make it remember its variables?

I have code files as attached at the bottom of this message.
First, question.php sends a question to javascript (via jQuery ajax) and display in html.
question.php file also do the sum and put it in the variable `$correctAnswer`or`$_SESSION[correct_answer]`.
Then, user types in his answer in html and javascript sends the answer to .check_answer.php (via jQuery ajax).
After that, php code in check_answer.php file compares the user answer with the variable `$correct_answer` or `$_SESSION[correct_answer]` to see if the answer is correct.

Problem is that the `check_answer.php` does not seem to remember the variable $correct_answer set in `question.php`, so it cannot correctly check the answer.
I tried to use `$_SESSION[correct-answer]` instead, but still the server side (php) does not remember the value inside `$correct_answer` or &`SESSION[correct_answer].`

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong here and how I can make php remember the variable for the correct answer?

Thank you,
Noby

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Ajax-powered Quiz</title>


    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Answer the following question. </p>
        <p id="question_text">Question</p>
        <p id="response_text">Response</p>

        <input id="your_answer" type="textbox">    
        <input id="submit_button" type="button" value="submit">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
$.ajax({
        url:"php/question.php"
}).done(function(data){
    $("#question_text").html(data);
});


function server_response(data) {
    $("#response_text").html(data);
}

function submit_answer() {
    alert("answer submitted!");
    var your_answer;
    your_answer = parseInt( $("#your_answer").val() );

    var send_object = {
        yourAns: your_answer
    };

    //$.get("php/check_answer.php", send_object, server_response);

  $.ajax ({
    url: 'php/check_answer.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: send_object,
    success: server_response
  });
}



$("#submit_button").click(submit_answer);
```

**question.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$numb1 = 2;
$numb2 = 3;
$_SESSION['correct_answer'] = $numb1 + $numb2;

echo "$numb1 + $numb2 = ?";

?>
```

**check_answer.php**

```
<?php

$your_answer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "yourAns");
echo "your answer is $your_answer!";

$correct_answer = $_SESSION['correct_answer'];
if ($your_answer == $correct_answer) {
    echo "You are correct!";
} else {
    echo "You are wrong!";
    echo "Correct answer is $correct_answer!";
}



?>
```

Comment: check_answer doesn't seem to be using `sessions`

Comment: use `session_start()` in check_answer.php

Comment: Thank you! It works by adding session_start() in check_answer.php as you said.  I was afraid of using it as I already used it in question.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not starting your session in `check_answer.php`.

so add `session_start()` in your `check_answer.php`. It will work:)

Answer (score 1):

In your check_answer.php file, at top start session first with `session_start()` method. It will work then.